# Making the WAF rule by CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I want to make the `WAF` as IP whitelist with `wafv2`

Currently My code is here

```
import { aws_wafv2 as wafv2 } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
const wafacl = new wafv2.CfnWebACL(this, "MyCfnWebAll",{
  name: `ee-${targetEnv}-waf`,
  scope: "REGIONAL",
  defaultAction: {
    allow:{
      customRequestHandling: {
        insertHeaders: [{
          name: 'my_allow_name',
          value: 'my_allow_value',
        }],
      },
    }
  },
  visibilityConfig:{
    cloudWatchMetricsEnabled: false,
    metricName: 'metricName',
    sampledRequestsEnabled: false
  }

});

new wafv2.CfnWebACLAssociation(this, 'WebACLAssociation', {
  webAclArn: wafacl.attrArn,
  resourceArn: lb.loadBalancerArn
})

const cfnIPSet = new wafv2.CfnIPSet(this, 'MyCfnIPSet', {

  addresses: ['23.186.72.133/32','143.32.1.45/32'],
  ipAddressVersion: 'IPV4',
  scope: 'REGIONAL',

  description: 'description',
  name: `ss-${targetEnv}-ipset`,
});
```

It can make the `WAF` ,association with the `LoadBalancer` and `ipSet`

However it lacks `rules`

I am searching the samples to code `rule` , however I could't find the good clue.

What I want to do is equivalent to this,

1. `Add my own rules and rule groups`
2. `choose doesn't match the statement(NOT)`
3. set IPset

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

For now, my reference is these.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-wafv2.CfnWebACL.RuleProperty.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-wafv2.CfnWebACL.html

I made the code like this below.

making the rule and try to set this in `rules` of wafv2.CfnWebACL

```
const ruleProperty: wafv2.CfnWebACL.RuleProperty = {
  name: 'name',
  priority: 123,
  statement: {
    ipSetReferenceStatement: {
      arn: cfnIPSet.attrArn
    }

  },
  visibilityConfig: {
    cloudWatchMetricsEnabled: false,
    metricName: 'metricName',
    sampledRequestsEnabled: false,
  }
}

const wafacl = new wafv2.CfnWebACL(this, "MyCfnWebAll",{

  name: `ss-${targetEnv}-waf`,
  scope: "REGIONAL",
  rules:[ruleProperty], ## add here
```

There comes the error like this

```
Resource handler returned message: "Error reason: You have used none or multiple values for a field that requi
res exactly one value., field: RULE, parameter: Rule (Service: Wafv2, Status Code: 400, Request ID: ce79fc3b-c
b96-4856-9d9f-12ea39407091, Extended Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: f2ef3c98-382f-1b21-2351-e3861e418623, H
andlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use this as a reference to write the rules.

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/6056#issuecomment-581583976

IPSet is written like this.

```typescript
　　　　　　　　{
      name: "CustomAllowIpSetRule",
      priority: 1,
      statement: {
        ipSetReferenceStatement: {
          arn: "xxxxxxx"
        },
      },
      action: { allow: {} },
      visibilityConfig: {
        sampledRequestsEnabled: true,
        cloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true,
        metricName: "CustomAllowIpSetRule",
      },
    },
```

Comment: THank you very much I added       `action: { allow: {} },` and it works.